# IOS OTA installation : capture .ipa file instead of installing

Tags: php, ios, ipa, ota, over-the-air

I want to direct-download an *.ipa* file instead of going through *itms-service* and installing the file on my iPhone. I cannot access the manifest *.plist* file because it’s dynamically made by PHP and disposed after the installation.

I tried changing safari user agent to iPhone so that it might download the file itself, but safari can't figure out what *itms-service* is. Is there anyway to capture and save the *.ipa* file with my iphone instead of installing it?

I've already tried `file_get_content` the with PHP and going through the installation with a download manager on my iphone none of them was working.

Comment: i think you can use some of common network attacks, when you are on the same network download the IPA file from your iPhone and from your computer use network monitoring softwares and capture all the network traffic and save it as a file.

Comment: Please tell exactly what you did. Were you able to download the `manifest.plist` file from the server (using the url parameter of the "itms-services" URL)? What is the content of the plist file?

Comment: no i could not download the manifest.plist because it is dynamically generated with php and removed after the request. @AndreasOetjen

Comment: can you introduce any of those softwares? @sci3nt15t

Comment: My fav. WireShark, there are so many tutorials online that you can find. it is X-platform so you can install it on any platform.

Comment: But itms-services will do exactly this. So if the URI is `itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://example.com/?manifest.plist`, you should be able to download `https://example.com/?manifest.plist` with cURL, some Web-Browser etc.